# differential equation for the susceptible infection susceptible model

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation:

$$\frac{di}{dt} = \beta\langle k \rangle i(1-i)-\mu i$$

I am ok with how I get there. I am doing some reading on my own and I need to understand how, given that the initial condition is $i_{0} = i(t=0)$ 
, I get the general solution to be:

$$ i = (1 - \frac{\mu}{\beta \langle k \rangle})\frac{C e^{(\beta \langle k \rangle - \mu)t}}{1+Ce^{(\beta \langle k \rangle - \mu)t}} $$

If I separate the differential equation I get:
$$\mu i \ di -\frac{di}{i} - \frac{di}{(1-i)} = \beta \langle k \rangle \ dt $$

Then I integrate both sides: 
$$\frac{\mu i^{2}}{2} - ln i + ln(1-i) + C = \beta \langle k \rangle t $$

Is this correct so far? because I have been trusting the process but I'm not getting to the correct answer. I am particularly unsure about the part with $\mu$ because when I use the initial condition to get C, substituting t=0 and $i_{0}=i$, I do not get what the book has for C. What they have for C is $$\frac{i_{0}}{(1-i_{0}-\frac{\mu}{\beta \langle k \rangle})}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake, in that the $\mu idi$ term should really be $\mu i dt$ (i assume it comes from the second term of the r.h.s. of the original equation). So instead, start with the original equation, and just divide both sides by the r.h.s. to get:

$$\frac{di}{\beta(k)i(1-i)-\mu i}=dt,$$

and integrate this (e.g. by partial fractions).

Comment: what would that look like? $$ \beta \langle k \rangle i(1-i)$$ is already factorized but that piece with $$\mu i$$ presents the challenge.

Comment: It's not already factorized. The denominator, when fully expanded in powers of $i$ is a (quadratic) polynomial. That can factor into roots $C(i+a)(i+b)$.

Comment: The expansion is $$\frac{1}{\beta \langle k \rangle i - \beta \langle k \rangle i^{2} - \mu i }$$. However, for a quadratic form we have $$ ax^{2} + bx + c$$ where $c$ would be the factors of $c$ which sum to give us $b$. In this case, i have factors  $\beta$ and $\mu$ but there is no corresponding $c$ in the denominator such that $$\beta \times \mu$$. Let's say I have $$\beta \langle k \rangle (i+1)(i-\mu) $$ I wont get back the denominator. I would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: If it's $ax^2+bx$ then it can be written as $ax(x+b/a)$, afterall, one of the roots must be 0. Or when in doubt, appeal to the quadratic equation.